# Duplicate legend with geom_vline() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to create this graphic:

```
aux_graf = structure(list(lines = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("h0", 
"ic", "median"), class = "factor"), values = c(21.19755, 23.06978, 
24, 22.13366)), .Names = c("lines", "values"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

dadosGraf = structure(list(dados = c(18.7997, 20.5035, 18.6214, 19.9192, 
21.117, 20.8353, 17.527, 17.078, 17.6197, 21.4255, 18.7545, 19.2026, 
18.4187, 20.7641, 21.0553, 17.5905, 18.7561, 18.9772, 20.3084, 
18.8988, 19.1688, 19.2898, 22.059, 18.5854, 17.8896, 21.1609, 
26.1371, 21.4737, 30.9934, 22.8421, 24.4133, 20.4137, 25.5475, 
21.8791, 22.6706, 24.7531, 25.7219, 22.6389, 26.2308, 26.7998, 
28.4708, 26.9941, 25.1489, 24.6179, 27.0194, 25.0589, 22.1119, 
20.3069, 23.6758, 27.1201, 29.6136, 25.9948, 18.223, 23.7336, 
22.4208), y2 = 1:55), .Names = c("dados", "y2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-55L))

gp2 <- ggplot(data = aux_graf)+
       geom_vline(aes(xintercept = values, colour=lines, linetype=lines), show_guide=TRUE)+
       geom_point(data = dadosGraf, aes(x = dados, y=y2), size=3.2, shape=21, colour = 'black', fill = 'grey')+
       theme_bw()
```

[image]

Now, i just want to change the labels, colour and linetype, but when I do, it adds another legend and I don't know why.

```
gp2 + scale_color_manual(name = '', labels = c(ic = 'Limites I.C.', median = 'Mediana', h0 = 'Hipotese Nula'), values = c(ic = 'red', median = 'black',h0 = 'grey40'))
    + scale_linetype_manual(values=c(ic = 'dashed', median = 'solid',h0 = 'dotted'))
```

[image]

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `override.aes` in combination with hiding the `linetype` legend. With:

```
gp2 + 
  scale_color_manual(name = '', 
                     labels = c(ic = 'Limites I.C.', median = 'Mediana', h0 = 'Hipotese Nula'),
                     values = c(ic = 'red', median = 'black',h0 = 'grey40')) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c('dotted', 'dashed', 'solid'))),
         linetype = FALSE)
```

you will get this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jaap! This worked out. I just changed the order inside the list get it right ('dotted' and 'dashed' is in wrong place).

Comment: @Jaap why do we need to define the linetype vector here? Can we put any default values here or do they need to be line types like "dashed"? Also how do I prevent this from overriding the labels I had set in scale_linetype_discrete?